# can we access file on azure vm via azure express route from on premises

Tags: remote-access, fileshare, azure-vm

I have a batch file on azure VM, which needs to be called from on-premises scheduler. Is it possible for us to access a file , on azure VM from on-premises machine

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes , we can , if port 445 is open on the Azure VM , then we can access the shared folder on Azure VM.
In the NSG , for inbound traffic , we need to open port 445